# How to change a block variable in Javascript set by "let"?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

If I declared a variable at the top of a Javascript file like:

```
let x = 3;
```

How can I change it in a function later? I know you can use window.x with variables set by var, but how do you change it if it was declared by let?

```
let x = 3;

function myFunction(){
   x = 4;
};
```

Comment: The way you wrote it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set a global variable `x`. It is available globally. Your function changes that global variable to 4. Simple as that.

```
let x = 3;

function myFunction(){
   x = 4;
};
console.log(x) // 4
```

To perhaps expand on this, what if you were to re-declare x inside `myFunction()`? That would shadow the global `x` you declared at the top. Global `x` would still be `3` even after you ran the code, but `x` would be `4` inside the function.

```
let x = 3;

function myFunction(){
    let x = 4; // this will now shadow the global x at the top
    console.log(x);
};
console.log(x) // 3
```

And if you were to run `myFunction()`...

```
myFunction(); // 4
```